# Laravel No Actualiza cambios en Producción

Tags: git, laravel, github, deployment

Tengo un proyecto en producción que he actualizado desde el repositorio y todo correcto, la cosa es que después de haber hecho **pull** de los cambios del repositorio **git** hay algunos cambios que no se ven reflejados en el funcionamiento de la aplicación, pero dentro del código del servidor esta todo actualizado y tal cual mi versión local del proyecto.

He probado de limpiar cache con **php artisan cache:clear** pero no ha hecho nada... sigue haciendo lo mismo.

Sabe alguien a que puede ser debido? Evidentemente he hecho **composer update** para que se descarguen las dependencias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas; por lo que he [leído](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37503726/1468942) el motivo es que aunque esté todo actualizado es necesario borrar la *cache* de las páginas generadas.

Para hacerlo debes ir a `storage/framework/views` y borrar lo que haya.

Si aún así no te funciona (y haces un refresh con `CTRL+F5`) mírate bien el [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503627/blade-view-not-reflecting-changes) que te comento porque el autor ya había intentado varias cosas; en concreto:

- Reiniciar navegador
- Borrar cache navegador (Ctrl+f5)
- hacer `php artisan cache:clear`
- hacer `composer dumpautoload`
- Borrar el fichero `Blade` (y peta). Recrear la página `Blade` sin contenido para que se refresque.